# Is there RFC3987(IRI validation) implementation done in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, uri, rfc, iri

Is there an implementation for [RFC3987 (Internationalized Resource Identifiers )](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) done in JavaScript so that I can use it to check if a string is a valid IRI? I need it for a script done with NodeJS.

I know that HTML doesn't support IRI links but I am not using to check HTML documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IRI: A utility for converting and parsing URIs and IRIs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/iri) can be helpful